# How can I comment ALAssetLibrary delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, alassetlibrary

I need to hide the Location service Popup window. I am using ALAsset library in my project. So one person told me to comment the below code from my project:
`(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` or "`startUpdatingLocation` and `stopUpdatingLocation`".

I searched this code in my project and didn't find it. I think it is in ALAssetLibrary Framework. How can I access this delegate and comment it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is from the CoreLocation framework. However, if you do not see it in your project, that means that, simply stated, it's not there! If you do not use in any way CoreLocation, there is no way that the alert you refer to may appear. So verify if in the Frameworks group in your project you have CoreLocation.framework, and also search for the following header:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

If you find the header, then it is possible that the class importing it is also using it. For this to be true, you must also find in the class a `CLLocationManager` object.